# How to find the grand total of a particular column and display it at the end?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is the detail.

```
date         |  Site   | Power
2017-05-11   |  ABC    | 171.123
2017-05-12   |  DEF    | 170.123
2017-05-13   |  GHI    | 172.123
2017-05-14   |  ABC    | 173.123
2017-05-15   |  DEF    | 170.123
```

I want to calculate the total power and display it at the end.

The query that I have used is

```
select  date, I_site,
        (
            select  sum(power) as Total_power
            from    mytable
            where   D_date between '2017-5-11' and '2017-05-15' and
                    I_site in (ABC,DEF,GHI,ABC,DEF)
        )
from    mytable
where   D_date between '3470' and '3500' and
        i_site in  (ABC,DEF,GHI,ABC,DEF)
group by date,I_site
```

The output I am getting is sum of the site values in the the same **Power** column.

Thank you

Comment: With that table data, what is the expected result? (Formatted text here too.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query seems mostly correct, but you don't need the `group by` clause because there's no aggregation in your `select` (the `sum` is inside the inner query, so that doesn't count). You're also missing the `power` field in your `select`, and that's why the sum is replacing the original `power` value in the third column of the result.

```
select   date, I_site, power,
         (
             select  sum(power) as Total_power
             from    mytable
             where   D_date between '2017-5-11' and '2017-05-15' and
                     I_site in ('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI')
         )
from     mytable
where    D_date between '3470' and '3500' and
         i_site in ('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI')
```

If the filters you're applying in the inner query and in the outside one are the same, you can write that this way too

```
select  date, I_site, power,
        sum(power) over () as Total_power
from    mytable
where   D_date between '3470' and '3500' and
        i_site in ('ABC','DEF','GHI')
```